Want to add custom div with product id in wix store, using wix site plugin
I created a review app for the Wix store and need to place a div with a dynamic data-idcorresponding to the product ID.
I made a site plugin but couldn't retrieve the product ID using $w('#productPage1').getProduct(), as it only works on the product detail page.
I need a universal solution for site plugins that works across all stores.
